# how to add custom error replacment messages in jquery validaiton plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add custom error replacement using jquery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) I would like to do custom error replacement like click here

```
$(function() {
    //simple example 1
    //click event for first button 

    $("#form1").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "business_email" ) {
                $("#bus_email").css('color',"#f42156");
                $("#busp_email").removeClass("field_validation_error hidden");
                $("#busp_email").addClass("field_validation_error");
            }
        },        
        rules: {
            business_email: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            business_email: "Please enter your firstname"
        }       
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fr0dc2es/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can get custom replacement message and act on *#bus_email*:

```
$(function() {
    //simple example 1
    //click event for first button 

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            business_email: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            business_email: "Please enter your firstname"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "business_email") {
                $("#bus_email").css('color',"#f42156");
                $("#busp_email").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#busp_email").html(error);
            } else {
                $("#busp_email").addClass("hidden");
                $("#busp_email").html();
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
          }
    });
});
```

[JQueryValidation Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: i would like to add style on span tag and remove the hidden in p tag as you can see in the html code

Comment: when there is a error i would like to add css class in span i tag with color code and to place the error message in P tag

Comment: currently your message go into a label with the id **business_email-error** why you don't want to use it ?
Your hidden class does nothing is it normal ?

Comment: It's ok i have corrected my code now it also act on *#busp_email* :)

Comment: yes getting the error it should not be appended in label should be p tag and also when keying the icon style also be removed when the field is valid

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle, `errorPlacement` function is being called and jQueryVal is working properly.

However,

1. Your `#busp_email` is shown but empty.
2. Your script logic is incorrect. Why do you remove a class, and add this class right after it? Why don't you hide it?

You **don't** need to check for every value in `errorPlacement`. It is not how it works. You shouldn't define a error placement for every `input` in a predefined error box - you should define a common placement logics by creating dynamic error messages after an `input` or in a specified place; or by appending an error to the specified alert; but definitely not by checking for every item.

Why default validation error placement is not suitable for you? What do you want to change? Describe it and I will try to help you - now you just provide an invalid code without any explanations.

Comment: have you seen that image link